# Coloring Gridlines in WPF Datagrid

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, datagrid

How can I set the color of the gridlines of a wpf datagrid? I can hide these lines with the property `GridLinesVisibility`, but I don't know how to color them. I tried it with the Borderbrush of rows and cells but I didn't succeed.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

You have the Properties `HorizontalGridLinesBrush` and `VerticalGridLinesBrush`

**Example**

```
<DataGrid HorizontalGridLinesBrush="Green"
          VerticalGridLinesBrush="Red"
          ...>
```

Answer (score 11):

You can change the **VerticalGridLinesBrush** and **HorizontalGridLinesBrush** properties of the Datagrid

```
 <Window.Resources>
       <SolidColorBrush x:Key="RedGridLine" Color="#FFFF4444" />
       <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BlueGridLine" Color="#554444FF"/>
    </Window.Resources>

<my:DataGrid VerticalGridLinesBrush="{StaticResource RedGridLine}"
        HorizontalGridLinesBrush="{StaticResource BlueGridLine}" >
```

For more

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/0202b0dd-38d9-4ad7-8576-d115922aeeec/

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dpatra/1803/

Answer (score 6):

To supplement the current answers, one can change the opacity at the same time in the resource to affect the gridlines:

```
 <Window.Resources>
     <SolidColorBrush x:Key="StackOverflowGray" Color="LightGray" Opacity=".3" />
 </Window.Resources>
```

...

Then the following usages has a lighter border shown in the datagrid:

```
<DataGrid GridLinesVisibility="All"
          HorizontalGridLinesBrush="{StaticResource StackOverflowGray}"
          VerticalGridLinesBrush="{StaticResource StackOverflowGray}"
```

Comment: Adding GridLinesVisibility="All" did the job for me. Thanks! +1